# Why are some of my divs appearing above my top bar while others aren't?

Tags: html, css

So I've been programing a game website and I've just created a new page for the player to get trophies for achieving stuff in the various games. While doing this though, I've discovered that my divs that contain the trophy text and image are appearing above the top navigation bar, which is confusing because nothing else across the website does that. I'm completely lost and it feels like I've tried everything.

Check out the code using the inspect tool here: [https://steelfoxgames.netlify.app/trophies]

I've tried getting rid of the attached JavaScript, changing the CSS, and narrowing down the HTML but nothing seems to work. The only thing that has given me the slight bit of progress is that if I delete both the class and the id of the trophy div it will appear below the top navigation bar but that really doesn't help me much because I need both of those things. I need the trophy div is act like everything else on the website and appear below the top navigation bar.

For a short sample of the base code, it's this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Steel Fox Games</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>Social Media</a>
    <a>Trophies</a>
    <a>Cookie Policy</a>
  </div>

  <h3></h3>
  <div class="trophy" id="AppleEater">
    <img src="TrophyImages/AppleEater.png" style="max-height: 200px; margin-right: 50px;">
    <div style="display: inline;">
      <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Apple Eater</h3>
      <h3>Eat 100 Apples in Snake</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

<h3></h3>
  <div class="trophy" id="AppleEater">
    <img src="TrophyImages/AppleEater.png" style="max-height: 200px; margin-right: 50px;">
    <div style="display: inline;">
      <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Apple Eater</h3>
      <h3>Eat 100 Apples in Snake</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

<h3></h3>
  <div class="trophy" id="AppleEater">
    <img src="TrophyImages/AppleEater.png" style="max-height: 200px; margin-right: 50px;">
    <div style="display: inline;">
      <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Apple Eater</h3>
      <h3>Eat 100 Apples in Snake</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<style>
body {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(237, 242, 218, 0.216), rgba(190, 92, 6, 0.233)), url("HomeImgs/GeometricTriangleBackground.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: "pixel";
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
.link {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 500%;
    line-height: 250%;
  }
  .subtitle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
  }

  h3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 250%;
  }
  
  div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .trophy {
    margin: auto 25%;
    background-color: rgb(69, 57, 43, 0.25);
    border-radius: 15px;
    filter: grayscale();
  }

  .trophy h3 {
    color: rgb(241, 235, 224);
  }
.topnav {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #e72a08;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: sticky;
    top: 5px;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
</style>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this help? `z-index`. https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/yurm56d3/2/ 

Comment: If you ever come across `z-index` again. I give you the hint to look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index . And you are welcome.